# Django, Initialize a field in child class from value in parent class

Tags: python, django, inheritance

In Django,

Say I have two classes, A and B.

B is the child of A. I want there to be an integer field in B that is the pk of A. I want this field in B to be initialized as such whenever I create a B object.

Thanks.

p.s. essentially I want to be able to access the pk of the parent object from the child class. If there is an easier/better way, please advise

Comment: This is the default behaviour with multi table inheritance in Django.

Comment: what is? How can I access the pk of A from the B model? B.id will give me only the pk of B, but I want the pk of A

Comment: Your answer is `ForeignKey` field - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey . It makes creating relationships frighteningly easy, and they're automatically available from both sides.

Comment: Try `b.a_ptr`, letting `b` be an instance of `B`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to set up class A as a foreign key to class B

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    ...
```

new b = B.objects.create(a=instance_of_class_a, ...)

Comment: If you want concrete inheritance, yes. If not, you want the ForeignKey field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're leveraging a ModelForm to create the instance of `B`, you can pass in the instance of `A` to your form and set the value there. This way you don't have to set it in the view code.

You'll also want to exclude the `a` field from the `B_Form`

```
class B_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        exclude = ('a',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = kwargs.pop('a')
        super(B_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        instance = super(B_Form, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.a = self.a

        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

and to leverage this form class in a view:

```
from your_app.forms import B_Form

def your_view(request, a_pk):
    a = get_object_or_404(A, pk=a_pk)
    b_form = B_Form(request.POST or None, a=a)

    if request.method == 'POST' and b_form.is_valid():
        b_form.save()

    return render('your-template.html', {'b_form': b_form})
```